# Failed build module _decimal of Python 3.6.5 on Ubuntu Trusty

Tags: python

I try to build Python 3.6.5 from source. On `make` command, I got this error:

```
$ Downloads/Python-3.6.5/Modules/_decimal/_decimal.c:42:4: error: #error "libmpdec version >= 2.4.1 required"
#error "libmpdec version >= 2.4.1 required"
```

`libmpdec` on Trusty is 2.4.0. So, I build myself libmpdec version 2.4.2 and place it in `~/.local`, and then add this line to `~/.profile`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="~/.local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

But still, got the same error messages(after restart shell). Before I will build and install mpdec version 2.4.2 from this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jonathonf/+archive/ubuntu/python-3.6/+packages), I want to know, how to add the proper option on the configuration of Python source to be succesfully build `_decimal` module with spesific mpdec library(location)?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. No need to add option `--with-system-libmpdec` as `libmpdec` is included with python source, or if still need using specific compiled version, add `-I`  flags in the configure command, e.g:

```
CFLAGS="-I/home/user/.local/include ./configure ...
```